# How do I disable END blocks in child processes?

Tags: perl, fork

I frequently use `fork` in programs that also have `END { ... }` blocks:

```
...
END { &some_cleanup_code }
...
my $pid = fork();
if (defined($pid) && $pid==0) {
    &run_child_code;
    exit 0;
}
```

The child process executes the `END {}` block as it is exiting, but usually I don't want that to happen. Is there a way to prevent a child process from calling the `END` block at exit? Barring that, is there a way for a program to "know" that it is a child process, so I could say something like

```
END { unless (i_am_a_child_process()) { &some_cleanup_code } }
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use B;
@{; eval { B::end_av->object_2svref } || [] } = ();
```

I thought there was a Devel:: module that also let you do this, but I can't find it now.

Of course, you can't safely do this if you are using arbitrary modules that might be using END blocks for their own purposes...

---

(edit by OP) You can get control over the END blocks with `B::end_av`. As a proof-of-concept:

```
END { print "This is the first end block.\n"; }
my $END_block_2_line = __LINE__ + 1;
END { print "This is the second end block.\n"; }
END { print "This is the third end block.\n" }

sub disable_specific_END_block {
  use B;
  my ($file, $line) = @_;
  eval {
    my @ENDs = B::end_av->ARRAY;
    for (my $i=$#ENDs; $i>=0; $i--) {
      my $cv = $ENDs[$i];
      if ($cv->START->file eq $file && $cv->START->line == $line) {
        splice @{B::end_av->object_2svref}, $i, 1;
      }
    }
  };
}

disable_specific_END_block(__FILE__, $END_block_2_line);
```

```
$ perl endblocks.pl
This is the third end block.
This is the first end block.
```

Usually something like this would be overkill for what I need, but I can see some cases where this would come in handy.

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of `Manip::END`.

Comment: Yes, it was Manip::END I was thinking of

Answer (score 18):

I don't think there's any way to prevent END blocks from running in a forked process, but this should let you detect it:

```
my $original_pid; BEGIN { $original_pid = $$ }

... # Program goes here

END { do_cleanup() if $$ == $original_pid }
```

Answer (score 15):

[perldoc -f exit](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html)

> The exit() function does not always exit immediately. It calls any defined `END` routines first, but these END routines may not themselves abort the exit. Likewise any object destructors that need to be called are called before the real exit. If this is a problem, you can call [`POSIX:_exit($status)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#_exit) to avoid END and destructor processing. See [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) for details.

Comment: The only problem is you have to catch _every_ possible way the child process might exit.  For example, if it dies, and you don't trap it, that will run the END blocks.

Comment: Also, you might _want_ object destructors to run, but not the END blocks.

Comment: @cjm: A late `eval 'END { use POSIX "_exit"; POSIX::_exit(0) }'` will prevent other `END` blocks from running, but not objects' `DESTROY` methods, and will catch `die` too.

Comment: Good to know, although there's a Windows issue where using `_exit` in one process will disable the END blocks in **all** the processes: http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=761630

Answer (score 6):

In a manner of speaking, the customary way to avoid them in `fork`ed children is with something like:

```
exec "true";
```

Or, should you find that too untrustworthy, these all work and are even use `use strict` compliant:

```
exec    $^X =>  -eexit;

exec ~~echo => ~~-echo;

exec ~~echo => !!-echo;
```

and the onomatopoetic

```
exec reverse reverse echo => ~~-echo;
```

**Rebmemer-** In Perl, there are no silly *questions*, but there may be silly *answers…* ☺

```
$ perl -Mstrict '-leprint ucfirst lc reverse-Remember'
```

Comment: Cute, though this also has issues with Windows.

Comment: @mobrule: Who doesn’t? I live in a world where that abomination doesn’t exist. If you’re a *Prisoner of $Bill,* then use the `$^X` approach.

Comment: I mean that calling `exec` from a child process doesn't avoid the `END` blocks on Windows, including `exec` to `$^X`.

Comment: @mobrule: *[expletive deleted]*

Comment: I'm running into this with DBI closing database handles in child processes. exec echo => "Finished doing ...<something>" at the end fixes it. Easier than setting InactiveDestroy on every database handle.

Answer (score 4):

This is code used by POE::Wheel::Run to do just what you want.  POE::Kernel::RUNNING_IN_HELL is true when `$^O eq 'MSWin32'`.  Adapt it to your needs.

```
sub _exit_child_any_way_we_can {
  my $class = shift;
  my $exitval = shift || 0;

  # First make sure stdio are flushed.
  close STDIN  if defined fileno(STDIN); # Voodoo?
  close STDOUT if defined fileno(STDOUT);
  close STDERR if defined fileno(STDERR);

  # On Windows, subprocesses run in separate threads.  All the "fancy"
  # methods act on entire processes, so they also exit the parent.

  unless (POE::Kernel::RUNNING_IN_HELL) {
    # Try to avoid triggering END blocks and object destructors.
    eval { POSIX::_exit( $exitval ); };

    # TODO those methods will not exit with $exitval... what to do?
    eval { CORE::kill KILL => $$; };
    eval { exec("$^X -e 0"); };
  } else {
    eval { CORE::kill( KILL => $$ ); };

    # TODO Interestingly enough, the KILL is not enough to terminate this process...
    # However, it *is* enough to stop execution of END blocks/etc
    # So we will end up falling through to the exit( $exitval ) below
  }

  # Do what we must.
  exit( $exitval ); 
}
```

Comment: This author seems to have discovered that `POSIX::_exit` won't doesn't suppress the `END` blocks on Windows^H^H^H^H^H^H^H IN HELL.

Answer (score 2):

Just set some kind of globally accessible flag, when you run `run_child_code()`.

There are a number of ways to do this, but I'd probably stick this into a package, and use a package scoped lexical to handle storage.  You could use a plain variable flag, too.  It's a bit simpler.  I like the package solution because it will easily work across multiple modules.

```
END { &some_cleanup_code unless ImaKid->get; }
my $pid = $fork;
if( defined($pid) && $pid == 0 ) {
    ImaKid->set;
    &run_child_code;
}

BEGIN {
    package ImaKid;

    my $child_flag;

    sub set {
       $child_flag = 1;
    }

    sub get {
       return $child_flag;
    }
}
```

Consider wrapping your fork management code into the same package to create a single consistent API for all your fork related needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did.
at the beginning of the program ( where I know no fork has happend yet ) 
Store the PID.
    my $parent_pid = $$;

```
#Then in the end block
END {
    my $current_pid = $$;
    if ( $parent_pid == $current_id ) 
        ##Here goes my cleanup code.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't very helpful to you, but I'll say it anyway: Don't use END blocks. There's usually a better way.

Comment: mobrule might not have control over the code that uses END blocks

Comment: END blocks can be quite useful.

Comment: Sometimes END blocks are the better way. For example this project I'm working on needs to save a hash reference before exists but there are a lot of scattered exit calls in it.